# android bluetooth pairing(Mac Known)

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

How to pair with Bluetooth (Mac Known).
Please provide Pairing and unpair code.It should be PIN related pairing.
Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: @SoroushA say it directly its out of ur capability .n  Thanx for replying.

Comment: @SoroushA any way i found a solution.saved my 75 dollars.